# View Magento's Rest API generated guest-cart in Store Website using URL with guest-cart id

Tags: checkout, cart, url, rest-api, guest-checkout

I have a requirement to show guest-cart items(created and items added using Magento rest API) on the Magento store website to initiate checkout from the website.

I tried http://storeurl.com/checkout/?cartId=asdfasdf with the guest-cart id that 
I generated using Rest API. But this doesn't work, It shows an empty cart.

Can anyone help me with this? Or at least I want to know, whether this could be possible or not?

Comment: that's not a rest api you generated there

Comment: @PhilippSander I created a guest cart via API(http://storeurl.com/rest/V1/guest-carts) and added items to it via postman and I want to view the cart and proceed to checkout in the browser. how to do that?

Comment: did you make sure that you use the same session?

Comment: I achieved this by creating a custom script to be called to check if quote id exists, if doesn't then my script finds random active product and adds to cart and immediately remove it too, This creates a active quote for the user and that cartId/quoteId can be used to add product to cart using RestAPI